# How do I remove specific paired tags?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# and trying to remove a specific pair of tags from string like

```
Remove <color=#FFFFFF>White </color>Not <color=#000000>Black</color>
```

And what I want is

```
Remove White Not <color=#000000>Black</color>
```

I tried to do it by myself but failed.Is there a way to do this?Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `I tried to do it by myself but failed` - Good , you are at the right place, if you could show how you did it, we can tell you why it failed and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you've already tried,

But this can easily be done by doing a Replace with RegularExpressions:

```
var original = "Remove <color=#FFFFFF>White </color>Not <color=#000000>Black</color>";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(original, "<color=#FFFFFF>(.*?)<\\/color>", "$1");
```

In the regex pattern, you can see I captured what's within the `color` tag to preserve the text inside, and then replaced the entire thing with that group capture, essentially removing everything around it.

Comment: Thank you! You really saved my day! I've spent 3 hours on it, how could I not find that simple answer......